# Indicating server unavailability in WP8

Tags: c#, networking, wpf-controls, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for a best practice to notify that connectivity to a server is available or not. Unavailability can either mean that there is no network connectivity or that the server is down.

Displaying a error message dialog is okay, but i also want to give the user a visual indikator that the server is available again (paint something green or so). Is there a standard way to indicate it?

I also need to disable various controls in different screens (like disableing a send button ...), so i have to handle network/server availability in all views?

any ideas?

i am using MVVM light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do this is to assign a global variable to check for availability.

```
eg. bool serviceAvailable=true or false;
```

Then disable button when a screen loads in the constructor of your wp7/wp8 app.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(serviceAvailable==false)
        {
        xamlButton.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        xamlButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

**or**

```
public void functionName()
{
if(doCheck()==true or false)
{
disable or enable button
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a background worker to achieve this.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker